# Does Spring Data JPA internally use Hibernate & why my app is working if I am not giving dialect property?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I just started learning Spring Data JPA, I connected to mysql in localhost and able to save a record but I am unable to understand why it is working if I am not giving dialect property in properties file and is hibernate a default implementation of spring data  instead of ibatis or Eclispe link, because in my pom.xml I just added the dependency of spring-data-jpa and never mentioned what kind of JPA implementation I want to use.

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/initsoftware
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=ppppppp
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxx
logging.level.root=DEBUG
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an `application.properties` I assume you are using Spring Boot and not just Spring Data JPA.

In order to use JPA with Spring Boot you would typically add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to your dependencies. This indeed comes with Hibernate out of the box as you can see [when you inspect the dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.7.RELEASE).

Spring Data JPA itself doesn't come with a JPA implementation. You have to add that.

iBatis is not a JPA implementation.

If the assumption above doesn't match your scenario you can use the [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to inspect your (transient) dependencies. The following is a good starting point.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

If you use a different build tool, it probably has a similar feature.